# screen shot from html to canvas using html2canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I am using html2canvas to taking screen shot from html page but it works fine only when the html's image tage contain the image from local src.if the image src from the live src it do not catch the image in screen shot i also refere the html2canvas issue . ans i also set the attribute allowTaint : true. but still as it is .can any one help what i miss?

```
var a = window.innerWidth,
n = window.innerHeight;
console.log('width='+a+"hight="+n);
$("canvas").attr("height", n), $("canvas").attr("width", a),$("canvas").attr("allowTaint",true),html2canvas(document.querySelector("body"), {
        canvas: canvas
    }).then(function(a) {
        var n = a.toDataURL();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../xhr/save-feedback.php",
            data: {
                img: n
            }
        }).done(function(a) {
            window.open("send_feedback.php?id=" + a, "_blank", "Send Feedback", "toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=0")
        })
    })
```

---

---

Comment: And  when i set true to allowTaint as true it gives an error  The operation is insecure.

Comment: Please describe, exactly what u want